# Fill Adjacent Table Column OnChange Based on Dropdown Menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, html-table, onchange

I'm in the midst of creating a photo gallery website that includes a store.  My programming experience is fairly limited, but over the last few months have developed a decent grasp on HTML and PHP.  I'm attempting to create a table that will allow users to select product specifications from a drop down menu.  Once selected, ideally the price of the product will appear in the adjacent column. This price should change if the user changes their selection from the drop down menu.  I'm entirely lost when it comes to outputting the price to screen.  For testing purposes I have included an alert, which creates a popup window in order to ensure that the price is changing   This is what I have thus far...

```
     <TD>
     <select id="photo" onchange="price(this.value)">
            <option value="$">--Please Select--</option>
            <option value="$2.50">6" X 12" - $2.50</option>
            <option value="$3.50">6" X 18" - $3.75</option>
            <option value="$5.00">6" X 24" - $5.00</option>
    </select>
    </TD>
    <TD>
    <script>
         function price(data)
           {
              value=data;
              alert(value);
           }

    </script>
    </TD>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your script so that it is between the head tags of your HTML document and change it to something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function price(data)
    {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById( "itemPrice" );
        myDiv.innerHTML = data;
    }
</script>
```

Then change the contents of your second <TD> block to this:

```
<td>
     <div id="itemPrice" name="itemPrice">
         Price will go here on selection
     </div>
</td>
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for the help.  For some reason it wasn't working with getElementsByName, so I switched it to getElementById.

Comment: Yeah, my Bad. `getElementsByName` is to get an array of elements with the given name. `getElementById` is the correct  function to use when you know that there is only one element with a given ID. I updated my answer with the correct function.